# Is this a good procedure to convert integer to char array in c?

Tags: c

I'm converting integer (12-bit) to char array with this code:

```
static char my_num_char[SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE]="";
static uint16_t my_counterB = 0;

my_num_char[0] = ( my_counterB / 1000) + 48;
my_num_char[1] = ( ( my_counterB - ( my_counterB / 1000 ) * 1000 ) / 100) + 48;
my_num_char[2] = ( ( my_counterB - ( my_counterB / 100 ) * 100 ) / 10) + 48;
my_num_char[3] = ( my_counterB % 10) + 48;
my_num_char[4] = '\n';
```

Is it a good way to do it or there are other more efficient ways?
I use this way because I want to pack several integers side by side and send these by serial. I use sscanf to retrieve the integers from the byte stream.

Comment: Do you want your leading zeros? Do you mind lack of null termination?

Comment: Why not sprintf?

Comment: I tried with sprintf but I didn't find a way to add a second integer to the char array

Comment: @FridaKahlo Could you show your attempt with `sprintf`? It may be easy to fix.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think the leading zeros help me retrieve the integers easier. About the null at the end, I'm not sure I use it when i retrieve the numbers, I add it because i'm used to.

Comment: You can also do some reaserches on itoa( ) function. It is not a standard function but you will easily find on the internet how to re-code it.

Comment: @FridaKahlo You didn't add null termination, you added a line break symbol.

Comment: Are you programming an embedded system that is severely constrained on memory?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This is for an arduino Due. I'm looking for a fast algorithm because i want to transfer via serial a lot of data. (an oscilloscope).

Comment: Why don't you just binary-transfer the data?

Comment: @Dariusz Can you elaborate a bit or I 'll investigate. Thanks

Comment: @FridaKahlo The limiting factor in serial transfer is always the UART, even at the fastest baud rates. You can pick the slowest algo for doing binary-to-decimal conversion, its speed is going to be much faster than the transfer speed of your UART. Switching to binary transfer is going to double your throughput, though, because you'd be sending two bytes instead of four characters.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm using the "native" serial port of the Due which is connected directly to the ARM. I have read that i can get 8Mb/sec. I will check binary transfer thanks.

Comment: @FridaKahlo At 84 MHz clock CPU has roughly 80 instructions to compute each byte. Your algorithm uses about 20 instructions to compute four bytes - roughly five per byte, with 75 instructions to spare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you have enough room in the buffer you can do:

```
pos=0;
sprintf(my_num_char+pos, "%04d\n", my_counterB);
pos += 5;
sprintf(my_num_char+pos, "%04d\n", my_counterZ);
```

Comment: Could be done with a single `sprintf` or `snprintf` like `snprintf(my_num_char, sizeof(my_num_char), "%04d\n%04d\n", mycounterB, mycounterZ);`

Comment: If you have both values at the same time.  Likely OP knows that as well.

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a function to do this for you, like [`snprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/).

Example:

```
char my_num_char[SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
int value = 747;
snprintf(my_num_char, SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE, "%d", value);
```

It's not about efficiency, it's about code cleaness.

Comment: I would recommend `snprintf` which is safer (e.g. when `SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE` is too small)